# How to execute VBA after Outlook Application_Startup event handler and after all folders sync?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to run a macro that moves emails received before today to a cabinet folder whenever Outlooks starts. The problem is that the `Application_Startup` event handler happens before Outlook is completely loaded and folders have synced. Consequently, all the emails that came in last night aren't moved to the cabinet when I open Outlook in the morning.

To fix this I created a custom class to instantiate an `Outlook.syncObject` which syncs all folders and provides an event handler when the syncing is complete. I create an object from this class within the `Application_Startup` event handler. However, this sync doesn't seem to actually retrieve any emails and also *seems* to complete before Outlook has even loaded.

It seems like being able to execute code after Outlook has done **all** of it's startup processes would be a common feature request. Thanks for any help.

This sample code simply shows me how many unread emails are in my inbox. If I close Outlook, send myself an email, then open Outlook, I need Outlook to load and a full sync to occur before generating the messagebox with the number of unread emails in my inbox.

Oulook `Application_Startup` event handler:

```
Dim mySyncInstance As New mySync

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    mySyncInstance.Initialize_handler
End Sub
```

Custom mySync Class Code:

```
Dim WithEvents mySync As Outlook.syncObject

Sub Initialize_handler()
 Set mySync = Application.Session.SyncObjects.item(1)
 mySync.Start
End Sub

Private Sub mySync_SyncEnd()
 MsgBox Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True").Count & _
    " Emails are unread in the main inbox."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to run a macro that moves emails received before today to a cabinet folder whenever Outlooks starts.

You may consider handling the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. So, you can get the mail item and decide whether you need to move it in a subfolder or not. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

Also you can create a rule and assign a VBA macro sub. The incoming instance of the mail item object will be passed as a parameter. For example:

```
public sub test(mail as MailItem)
  ' do whatever you need
end sub
```

As an alternative way you can handle the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Items class which is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than 16).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sounds like I know what the options are. The 'ItemAdd' event would be great although I'm also using this for proxy boxes that may have 50 to 100 emails when Outlooks boots up in the morning so it sounds like that event will not fire. I may end up just adding a 'Sleep' for thirty seconds or so after the 'Application_Startup' event. Thanks again!

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev, is there any other way for more than 16 mails than ItemAdd?? For example if you open Outlook after a vaccation and receive thousand of mails.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Items.ItemAdd event on the Inbox folder?

Comment: That would certainly work. However, I only need to execute the code once per day (or Outlook startup) and I'd like to display a message at the end indicating how many emails were moved.

Comment: You do that in the right way handling the [SyncEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866270(v=office.15).aspx) event. There is no better way.

Comment: Check if MailItem.ReceivedTime is less than when Outlook started up.

Comment: If you really want a solution that runs at the proper time once on startup, use the Application_Startup event to set a boolean value to true, and then 1) call your custom code from the SyncEnd event only when boolean = true and 2) set that boolean = false. If you want to, you can also add a button on the ribbon which sets your boolean to true, so that you can test or kick off the process during the day if you want